# Xubuntu 14.04 - Closing lid doesn't immediately trigger xscreensaver

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, suspend, lock-screen, xscreensaver

When I close the lid of my laptop, it suspends. When I open the lid and push a key, it wakes as expected. If it has been five minutes (the timer for `xscreensaver`), the screen will be locked. If it has been less than five minutes, the screen will not be locked.

- Suspending from the user menu (Action Buttons panel plugin) works correctly, i.e. xscreensaver is triggered and locks the screen on wake.
- Light Locker is disabled, and I'm using xscreensaver.
- xscreensaver settings:
  Blank after 5 minutes
  Lock screen after 0 minutes
  xscreensaver's power management options are disabled.
- Power Manager settings:
  On AC -> When laptop lid is closed -> Suspend
  On Battery -> When laptop lid is closed -> Suspend
  Extended -> Lock screen when goin for suspend/hibernate -> checked
- Initial install was Xubuntu 13.04, then updated to 13.10, and finally 14.04.
- Problem did not exist with initial 14.04 upgrade.
- uname -srvpio = Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:12 UTC 2014 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
- Laptop model: ASUS X53E
- Manually locking screen, or timer activated screensaver before screen closure remains locked after wake.

Comment: I should also add that I've done some Googling for "xubuntu closing lid suspends without locking screen" and some variations on wording, and found other problems which occur in similar circumstances (black screens, not suspending) but nothing on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have logind-handle-lid-switch set to true:

```
$ xfconf-query -vl -c xfce4-power-manager
/xfce4-power-manager/lock-screen-suspend-hibernate  true
/xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-lid-switch       true
```

You can get get to a GUI to set logind-handle-lid-switch by:

`$ xfce4-settings-editor`

I had the same issue until I did that.

On a sidenote: 
I was not able to get suspend to work on my laptop with the open source driver.  I had to install fglrx-updates (the proprietary AMD graphics driver) to get suspend to work properly.  *sad face*

You can find proprietary video drivers with the Additional Drivers program.